# How to display categories any sub categoires from database

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering how would I display my hierarchical data to create my categories and endless sub categories using PHP & MySQL?

A quick example of how my PHP & MySQL code should look like would help out a lot.

MySQL table categories structure

```
id  parent_id   category
1   0           a & w
2   0           b & f
3   1           c & sometimes y
4   1           d
```

Comment: how would that help me at all I already have my table structure.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have hierarchical support; check your tables to ensure you can get what you want out of it.

Comment: i was looking how I can output the code using PHP.

Comment: @Gaurav the link you provided is basically the same answer I got in the comments.

Comment: @html5, OMG Ponies tried to tell you that your current structure has some problems if you really want it to be able to handle an unlimited number of sub trees. The reason is explained under the link supplied.

Comment: Because PHP can only work of what you get from MySQL...  And +1 to what cmmi said

Comment: then what is the recommended structure?

Comment: You guys are not answering html5's 'answerable' question. I've posted a solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course it's possible. This code will render a `<ul> <li>` hierarchical tree, regardless of number of levels

```
<?php
  //Connect to mysql server
  $cn = mysql_pconnect("server", "username", "password");
  mysql_select_db("database_name");
  $rs = mysql_query("SELECT id, parent_id, category FROM categories", $cn);
  $childrenTree = array(); //Will store an array of children for each parent
  $categoryNames = array(); //Will store category name for each id
  //We fill $childrenTree and  $categoryNames from database
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
     list($id, $parent_id, $category) = $row;     
     $categoryNames[(string)$id] = $category;
     $parent_id = (string)$parent_id;
     if(!array_key_exists($parent_id, $childrenTree)) 
         $childrenTree[$parent_id] = array();
     $childrenTree[$parent_id][] = (string)$id;
  }

 //Main recursive function. I'll asume '0' id is the root node
 function renderTree($parent = "0"){
    global $categoryNames;
    global $childrenTree;
    if($parent != "0") echo "<li> ", $categoryNames[$parent], "\n";
    $children = $childrenTree[$parent];
    if(count($children) > 0){ //If node has children
       echo "<ul>\n";
       foreach($children as $child)
          renderTree($child);
       echo "</ul>\n";
    }
    if($parent != "0") echo "</li>\n";
 }
 renderTree();  //This renders the hierarchical tree
?>
```

The resulting HTML for your example will be:

```
<ul>  
  <li> a & w
    <ul>
        <li> c & sometimes y </li>
        <li> d </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> b & f </li>
</ul>
```

That will render in a browser like this:

- a & w

  - c & sometimes y
  - d
- b & f

I repeat, this works for any level of nesting.
Hope this helps.

Comment: for some reason I can vote up your excellent answer:( But I did accept as the best answer.

Comment: Ah, it's cause you need a little more points. Ok, no problem. Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia ;)

Comment: hi its great answer now i want to edit the category name when main category contain more then one category  at that time i want to display both display the its subcategories...how can achieve it.....any help appricated..thanks again...!

Comment: @pratik, This example shows many categories in the main one. I don't understand what you want

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado: i mean when i select the computer->sub1->sub1of1...,if i edit this category then i want to two selected box and one input box.in first select box computer will be selected,,second select box sub 1 will be selected and last input text which is seted the sub1of1.how can achieve it.