# How to create xml category/subcategory hierarchy from sql table in flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex, list, iteration, hierarchical

I have sqlite table named categories with fields id, name, and parent_id. Sample data is much like:

id       name             parent_id
1        products            0
2        tools               0
3        computer            1
4        monitor             1
5        antivirus           2

Now I want to create hierarchical xml tree from the above data. Categories with parent_id 0 are obviously the top nodes.

Thanks & Regards,
Farhan Ahmed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think sqlLite allows you to directly output xml in the way that something like SQL Server does, so I think you'll have to "brute force" it.  In other words, you request all the top level nodes, then loop through them and get all their children, then loop through each child and get each children, etc., etc.  You might want to do this in more of a "just in time" way, by only asking for the children of a node when it is opened by the user.

Comment: see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828089/php-mysql-how-to-display-categories-any-sub-categoires-from-database I exactly want this solution but in AS3.0, can some body help?