# Optimizing / Simplify Query of Multi-Layer Category

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table ( name: `item_categories` ) having the following schema:

```
id                  INT(11)           PRIMARY KEY, AUTO INCREMENT
category_name       VARCHAR(100)      NOT NULL
parent_id           INT(11)           NOT NULL, Default 0
```

Sample Data:

```
id  category_name   parent_id
=============================
1   Fruit           0
2   Animal          0
3   Furniture       0
4   Apple           1
5   Orange          1
6   Cat             2
7   Dog             2
8   Black Dog       7
9   White Dog       7
```

If I have to list out the categories with their parent categories, I have to loop through the database table many times.

My question is: How can I simplify the loop task?

Current loop task query:

```
// 1st query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM item_categories";
$rs = $db->query($sql);
while($row = $db->result($rs)) {
  if((int)$row['parent_id'] === 0) {
    // it is parent
    echo $row['category_name'] . PHP_EOL;
  } else {
    $category = $row['category_name'];

    // it has parent
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM item_categories WHERE id=" . $row['parent_id'];
    $rs2 = $db->query($sql);
    $row2 = $db->result($rs);
    $parent_id = (int)$row2['parent_id'];
    while($parent_id != 0) {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM item_categories WHERE id=" . $row['parent_id'];
      $rs2 = $db->query($sql);
      $row2 = $db->result($rs);
      $parent_id = (int)$row2['parent_id'];
      $category = $row2['category_name'] . ' > ' . $category;
    }
    echo $category;
  }
}
```

Which will output:

```
Fruit
Animal
Furniture
Fruit > Apple
Fruit > Orange
Animal > Cat
Animal > Dog
Animal > Dog > Black Dog
Animal > Dog > White Dog
```

Comment: Take a look at the answer marked as correct in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828089/php-mysql-how-to-display-categories-any-sub-categoires-from-database . Basically you get full list only once (one query), format it and then use recurency to build tree.

Comment: Smart answer using 1 single SQL call only.

Comment: Let me know if you managed to write your code based on the link i gave you - if not, i'll try to post answer with some code examples to help you.

Comment: that answer will be fine, but if you wish to earn some credits by answering this question, please do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link i gave you in the comment - try this:

```
function renderBreadcrumbs($db, $id, $path = null) {
    $res = $db->query("SELECT id, parent_id, category_name FROM item_categories WHERE id = " . $id);
    $row = $db->result($res);

    $path = $row['category_name'] . ' > ' . $path;

    if($row['parent_id'])
        $path = renderBreadcrumbs($db, $row['parent_id'], $path);

    return $path;
}

$res = $db->query("SELECT id, parent_id, category_name FROM item_categories ORDER BY parent_id ASC");

while($row = $db->result($res)) {
    $breadcrumb = null;

    if(!$row['parent_id'])
        $breadcrumb .= $row['category_name'];
    else
        $breadcrumb .= renderBreadcrumbs($db, $row['parent_id'], $row['category_name']);

    echo $breadcrumb . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: The codes do not list the output as expected. Probably due to different structure with the answer you quoted.

Comment: Ok, i'll create same table here and check where is the problem, will update answear in a few minutes.

Comment: i think `array_walk()` or `array_walk_recursive()` may be helpful.

Comment: I have edited my answer - it should work now assuming your `$db->result()` method returns associative array. If it returns numeric one already, just change back `array_values($row)` to simply `$row`.

Comment: Ohh yeah, sorry - was because it was based on list structure, not breadcrumb one... anyway - answer is edited, corrected and simplified.